# .htaccess redirect code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I currently use the following code for my htaccess file. It redirects to https://www.example.com

```
#if not forum.example.com and not ssl then redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\. 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

#redirect if https://forum.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

The problem I have is when I go to

```
http://www.example.com
```

, this code makes it redirect to

```
https://www.www.example.com
```

instead of

`https://www.example.com`.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

If you require additional information to assist, just let me know.

Comment: www is added in the first rewrite rule without checking previously if is already part of the URL.

Comment: Don't really know the proper code for that.

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm new here, but thanks for the guide! I read through it and accepted the last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rewrite rule is executed if 2 negative conditions are met: Not `forum` and not `SSL`, but the rewrite inserts **www** always, even when it is already in the URL. It is not previously checked.

I think the best way to correct the problem without modifying the actual rules, except removing the **www** from the first substitution, is by adding another rule at the begining, like this:

```
#non-www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#if not forum.example.com and not ssl then redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\. 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L] 

#redirect if https://forum.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

What the added rule does, is to rewrite any URL without `www` to one with `www`. The resulting URL is then presented to the other rules.

I don't know if these 2 last rules work as intended, I guess they do. I am just trying to solve the **www** duplication issue in the question.

Hope this helps.